# USB debugging in lenevo vibe p1 through android studio

Tags: usb-debugging, android-device-manager, android-sdk, android-pc

I am using android studio in dell inspiron laptops. I want to use my lenevo vibe p1 phone for usb debugging. I have installed oem usb driver for my phone in my laptop. Also enabled usb debugging option in my phone. But if I try to test the app through usb debugging, it shows no device connected or found etc.(even though I connected my phone through a usb cable.

Answer (score 1):

Download PdaNet+ software from below link, and enable debugging mode in your mobile.All devices can easily connect as a Debugging.Its working for me.Try it.I hope it is definately usefull for you.This software is avilable windows as well as MacOS.

```
http://pdanet.co/a/
```